# F# Why can't I use the :? operator in F# interactive?

Tags: f#, typechecking, f#-interactive

I am trying to check if a variable is of a certain type like so:

```
let s = "abc"
let isString = s :? string
```

but in F# interactive, I get the following error:

`error FS0016: The type 'string' does not have any proper subtypes and cannot be used as the source of a type test or runtime coercion.`

Why is this happening? I expect isString to be a bool.

Comment: That's because you're trying with a sealed type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because you are trying with a sealed type.

Try instead this:

```
let s = box "abc"
let isString = s :? string
```

There is no point in doing this coercion tests with sealed types since they can't have any subtype and that's what the error message is telling you.

The `box` keyword will always return an object, whether the source is reference type (as in this case) or a value type, in which case it will "box" it.

Comment: I would have boxed in the second line so that s remains a string, but it's all right as is.