# How to mimic F# compiler type checking?

Tags: f#

In F#, I can write a function `(fun x -> x * x)` and confirm it has type `int->int` because the following code compiles:

```
let typeCheck<'T> (x:'T) = ()
typeCheck<int->int> (fun x -> x*x)
```

On the other hand, `GetType` for this function doesn't agree with `typeof<int->int>`:

```
> (fun x -> x*x).GetType() = typeof<int -> int>
val it : bool = false
```

If not `GetType()` and `typeof`, what functions can I call to mimic the type-checking done by the compiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why `GetType` of a specific lambda function is not the same as `typeof<int -> int>` is that the F# compiler generates a new class for the function which inherits from `int -> int`. In other words, the types are not the same, but the type you get via `GetType` inherits from `int -> int`.

You can check for this easily using `IsAssignableFrom`. The following is `true`:

```
typeof<int -> int>.IsAssignableFrom((fun x -> x*x).GetType())
```

Comment: Seems a bit weird that this implementation detail is exposed to the user. I would expect that ":?" would compare `int -> int` to `int -> int`, even if behind the scenes technically the two were different. The sealed thing makes it not really matter but still....

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:?` operator to check based on type. I boxed it because `(int -> int)` is a sealed type.

[F# Why can't I use the :? operator in F# interactive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452303/f-why-cant-i-use-the-operator-in-f-interactive)

```
> let f = box (fun x -> x*x);;
val f : obj
> f :? (int -> int);;
val it : bool = true
```

If you wanted to build your typecheck function you could use this. A 'T and a thing of type 'T, they would always have the same type so I made x an object here, and you can box it before looking at it. However you probably don't need to do this, so if you're new to F# you may be working harder than you need to.

```
let typeCheck<'T> (x: obj) =
    x :? 'T 
//which is the same as
x :? (int -> int)
//so you probably don't need to define your own :)
```

Comment: I am only just learning this. The type of `(int -> int)` appears to be an abstract type that the framework calls ``Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]``. So not sealed. The type of a concrete lambda such as `(fun x -> x*x)` appears to be a type generated by the F# compiler which is sealed and has ``FSharpFunc`2`` as its immediate base class.